# Illegal character range near index 17

Tags: java, exception

I'm new to java and i wanted to make an input checker class that when you enter a value (be it int, string or double) it would check if it doesn't contain illegal characters and if it does, return false.

Now, even if it probably sucks and doesn't make much sense, i managed to make a code to do that, the problem is that it gives me a Illegal character range near index 17 exception.

This is the code:

```
public class InputChecker {
    public InputChecker()
    {

    }

    public boolean checkString(String string)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1234567890,.-\\!'~#\\@*+%{}<>\\[\\]|\"\\_^]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        return matcher.find();

    }

    public boolean checkDouble(double theDouble)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,-!'~#@*+%{}<>\\[\\]|\"\\_^]");
        String sDouble = String.valueOf(theDouble);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sDouble);
        return matcher.find();
    }

    public boolean checkInt(int theInt)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,-!'~#@*+%{}<>\\[\\]|\"\\_^]");
        String sInt = String.valueOf(theInt);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sInt);
        return matcher.find();
    }


}
```

Comment: Explanation given in your question is not clear enough. You have 3 methods, where you are getting exception?

Comment: Jesus, i'm sorry.
I'm getting the error in the checkString method.

Comment: why do you want to use regex for this anyway.  I would rather use Integer.valueOf (String)

Comment: checkDouble and checkInt are needless, a double or int will never equal any of the values in your exclude list. They'll only ever be string representations of a the numbers.

Comment: As i said, i'm a total beginner, but i guess that projects are the best way to learn.
Could you explain the Integer.valueOf(String)?

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: It converts a String to an int.

Comment: Yeah i don't get it, maybe i'm just dumb.
How can it check if a string contains an invalid character if it just converts it to an int?

Comment: You appear to have demonstrated the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/218012). I had the same problem  when I first joined the site, but the truth is: following the advice on that FAQ entry will help you find the correct answer to what you are looking for.

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance and i won't do the same error again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `checkString` method Use Escape character for dot `\\.` and `?!` instead`!` as dot is special character and lookaheads are defined by `?!`.

As I am completely *anaware* what you are trying to do.

---

You can use `\\w+` to match whether `String` contains one or more *Word Characters*.

Comment: Basically, i need to check if the characters in a "human" name are valid, as i need it to check names in a program that books a room in the motel i work in.

Comment: So do you want to check whether name contains only alphabets or not?

Comment: I just tried to add \\. and ?! and it works!
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Every regex has the same error. You define character classes:

```
[...]
```

And you use `-`s in them. Inside a character class, `-` specifies a range: all the values between (inclusive) the ascii values of the two characters on the right and left.

It appears that you really want to have the `-` as part of the character class. In this case, simply move it to the front (the same for the others as well; note: I removed unnecessary backslashes):

```
"[-1234567890,.!'~#@*+%{}<>\\[\\]|\"_^]"
```

Comment: Moving of the dash to the end also helps. I had this problem with the regexp `[A-Za-z0-9_-@]+`. I changed it to `[A-Za-z0-9_@-]+` and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following exception was thrown due to the presence of Cyrillic characters in the range: `[а-я]` in my Spring Boot project. I replaced this range with `\p{L}` and it worked. You can find a description here: [regular-expressions.info/unicode.html](http://regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)