# Regex pattern to check if string has no special characters - Java

Tags: java, regex, spring, java-8, special-characters

I want to check if a string contains no special characters like @, $ etc and include only alphanumerics and special characters like "-", "."

I have used regex pattern as below, but none of them is working

1. `String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]*$";`
2. `String regex = "+/^[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$/i";`
3. `String regex = "^([-.A-Za-z0-9]){1,20}$";`
4. `String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]*";`

`if (r.getTest().matches(regex)){}`

**Edit:**

The regex in the answers is working fine, but when added it as condition in the code, the code is always returning false, saying it contains special characters, when all I have in the string are alphanumerics, and dots(.).

None of them is working. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal character range near index 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277208/illegal-character-range-near-index-17). Also see [java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index](https://www.yawintutor.com/java-util-regex-patternsyntaxexception-illegal-character-range-near-index/) and search for still more. It’s always a good idea to paste your error message into your search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `\` before the `-`. You should use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]*$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNp7Ma/1)

Answer (score 2):

I see one big issue with your first regex, and that's the `-`. Between `[` and `]`, **every** `-` means a range except if it's escaped, or if it's the first or last character. With what you have now, I get an exception:

```
Exception java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 13
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]*$
```

If I move the `-` to the end, I can successfully create a pattern that should work.

Comment: This works for me. Using `String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$";` I get `true` for `abc.def` and `false` for `§!\"#€%&/()=?\``.

Comment: @OleV.V. are you using matches or contains method?

Comment: @Shinchan `matches()`. As in `"abc.def".matches(regex)`.

Comment: I prefer to reuse `Pattern` instances. I create a `private static final Pattern MY_PATTERN`, then use `My_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()`. When you call `input.matches(regex)`, this is done in the background, but the regex is compiled every time. Since `Pattern` is immutable (and therefore thread-safe), it's better to reuse those.

Comment: @OleV.V. no it's not working for me

Comment: @RobSpoor yeah, I tried using pattern but that isn't working too

Comment: What's the input you're using, and what is the output you expect?